# Diagraming MS Office Object Models

Tags: ms-office, class-diagram, object-model, diagramming

I want to visualize the various object models used by Microsoft  Office, but I cannot locate a decent resource.

Is there a way for me to do this programmatically, or is there a good resource of up-to-date diagrams that already exists?

For example, I would like to get a visual understanding of the multiple models used in Microsoft Access, such as the "Access object model," the "VBA object model," the "ADO object model," etc.

Likewise, I need to develop some Access solutions that will interact with Excel and Word (and vice-versa), so I need to grasp their object models too.

Ideally, I'd love something interactive that would allow me to search for a property/method, or collapse/expand elements in the hierarchies.

On a related note, can I use VBA to generate a list of all the objects in a given model/reference, along with the objects' membership paths?

Answer (score 1):

I can't recall ever seeing maps, else I would have horded them by now. There are searchable and collapsible/expandable .chm help files that you can download - these are always my quick and easy goto references:

Office 2013 VBA Documentation: 
https://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/download/details.aspx?id=40326

(I've never seen 2016 versions)